# How do I represent a change in state programmatically - Capturing Player Substitutions

Tags: encryption, programming-languages, hash

I'm trying to create a data set for training a neural network for sports application.  I'm trying to capture the impact player substitutions on points scored by a team.  I have sets of substitutions (Jones for Smith) (Smith for Davis) etc. that I'm trying to represent with a unique number.  For example every time my data set included a Jones for Smith substitution the function/program/hash would produce the same number.

I looked into Hash Codes (MDA, Sha), but these do seem to be the right way to go.  I'm sort of stumped on this one. If anyone has come across a similar situation or has some programming wizardry they would care to share I would appreciate it.   Thanks.

Comment: Is it important to you that your hashes are highly likely to be unique - or is it OK that e.g. a Jones for Smith substitution happens to collide with a David for James substitution?

Comment: Will - To train the neural network correctly, I need to avoid collisions.   Jones and Smith will each have a unique primary key. Would it be easier to come up with some sort of function that does a hash of the two primary keys where order matters - Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a string of the primary keys, along the lines of substited,substituted for, next substituted, next substituted for, etc. e.g.  "Jones,Smith,Smith,Davis".  An MD5 hash of this string, whilst not guaranteed to be unique, is probably going to be unique enough for your purposes.